# How accurate are altimeters in bike computers?

Tags: bike-computer, climbing, hills

I bought a bike computer with a pressure-based altimeter (Sigma 14.16 STS). It gives gradient of current hill with 1% resolution, current altitude with 1 meter resolution, and total climbed amount with 1 meter resolution.

How accurate are these readings?

Comment: How consistent is the weather between the start and end of your ride?  Starting in the cold rain and finishing in hot sunlight will give an artificial increase to total elevation.

Comment: How accurate do you need it to be? If it's off 1 meter or 5 meters how bad would that be?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The bike computer is based on the relationship between altitude and air pressure. Even though it has 1 meter resolution, it is still constrained by the air pressure around you. About 11.3 Pascal difference in air pressure is counted as one meter.

One thing to consider is that most houses have a slight 10 Pascal negative pressure caused by the ventilation system. Thus, if you bring the bike indoors, you may see its altitude raised by 1 meter and if you go out of your house with your bike, you may see its altitude reduced by 1 meter even though your house does not have a 1 meter ascent in its doorway.

Another thing to consider is that pressure can drift over time. I rode for 1.4 hours (1 hour 24 minutes) when pressure was drifting 40 Pascals per hour. This was 56 Pascal total drift. It should theoretically cause a 5 meter difference in the altitude (the endpoint of the ride was the same as the starting point). It gave exactly this difference. (Actually, I started the bike computer outdoors and when ending the ride outdoors, it gave the 5 meter difference; when I brought the bike indoors it gave 1 more meters of difference due to the 10 Pascal negative pressure I explained.)

This 40 Pascals per hour pressure drift is typical for changing weather. I looked at a one month long historical graph of air pressure and only twice in this month did the pressure drift faster than 40 Pascals per hour. So my example ride of 1.4 hours did have a truly changing weather. Most rides of 1.4 hours give less than 5 meters of altitude drift.

There are some ways the cyclecomputer is helping you to avoid unintended pressure drifts.

Firstly, good cycle computers (such as this Sigma 14.16 STS) store the current altitude when going to sleep and recalibrate automatically when waking up from sleep. Thus, you will not get pressure drift if the bike is parked for a long amount of time (my example 1.4 hour ride actually had a 2.5 hour long time being parked inbetween at another location than my home -- I didn't count it for the ride length).

Also, good cycle computers allow you to set several home locations and their altitudes. This Sigma 14.16 STS has two such home locations. I set one to the altitude of my home and the other to the altitude of my workplace. It is very easy to reset the current altitude to be any of these home altitudes. Good cycle computers also allow you to set the current altitude to be anything albeit with a bit more button presses than resetting to one of the home altitudes. So if you know your current altitude and are willing to take some time to enter it to the cycle computer, you can do so.

However, the total climbed amount is a very ill-defined and inaccurate concept if riding in a non-mountainous area.

For my 1.4 hour long ride, a local map service gave 471 meters of climbing. Google Maps gave 188 meters of climbing. The cycle computer measured it as 301 meters of climbing out of which 1 meters was the outdoors-to-indoors drift and 5 meters was the ambient air pressure drift so without drifts it gave 295 meters.

Why the difference between local map service and Google Maps? Why the difference between a map service and cycle computer?

The difference between local map service and Google Maps is probably due to Google Maps having less accurate altitude data in my area. If it is using a coarse altitude grid, it is not measuring every single small hill. Thus, it gives less total climbed amount due to the inaccuracy of the data.

If we take the 471 meters of total climbing given by the local map service as accurate, why does not the cycle computer measure the total climbed amount as 471 meters but rather measures it as 295 meters (plus drift)?

The reason is what you count as a hill. The cycle computer having 1 meter resolution cannot count hills smaller than 1 meters as a hill. Also, counting a 1-meter hill as a hill could cause some minor variations in local air pressure to increment the total climbed amount counter even though the terrain was completely flat!

Thus, the cycle computer must set some threshold. I don't know what the threshold of this Sigma 14.16 STS is. The cycle computer then counts only hills larger than the threshold. If riding in a mountainous area, it gives very accurately the total climbed amount. If riding in very flat terrain, you might want to count even the smallest hill which the cycle computer doesn't do.

Also, air pressure varies between 96 000 Pa and 104 000 Pa typically near the sea level. Thus, the maximum amount the cycle computer can reasonably drift is about 700 meters. Of course this can only occur if the variation between 96 000 Pa and 104 000 Pa occurs when riding the bike. If it occurs when parked, the cycle computer doesn't count it. So it is extremely unlikely to ever encounter this 700 meter altitude drift, but in theory it is possible.

---

I have used my altimeter now for nearly 3 years. I always reset it at home to the altitude of my home (38 m). The largest error I have ever seen is that when riding to work and back (45 km), it showed 2 m instead of the correct value (38 m). This happened when the ride had a very intense rain shower, and I stopped below a bridge to wait for rain to stop, then after half an hour of wait and looking at rain radar I concluded the rain will last for a long amount of time (narrow but long rain cloud, and winds were such that the cloud would stay over me for a long time) but if I just ride 5 km in the rain, I can ride away from below the rain cloud. So during the ride, the half an hour of wait meant that the bike computer was sleeping, setting the current altitude in memory, and after waking up recalibrating the pressure.

This 36 m error on a route 45 km long and having about 460 m climb is approximately 8% error in altitude climbed. Considering that altitude climbed is not a well-defined quantity, it's not much. For example if using a single map service with low-resolution topographical data and another map service with high-resolution topographical data, they tell vastly different numbers as altitude climbed. Also a bike computer will have to define somehow what counts as a "hill". An altimeter with 1 meter resolution could count local pressure variations and random noise as altitude climbed, so they probably have to restrict it so that you need to climb at least 2-3 meters for it to count as hill. I understand that the original Avocet altimeter bike computers had a much poorer resolution of 4 m than altimeters today have, and required 10 meter climb for a climb to count as a hill.

So an Avocet altimeter would probably say less meters climbed than a modern Sigma altimeter would today.

Comment: The pressure drift shows in the fact that if you ride a circuit, a route back to the starting point, climb and descent should be identical. They are almost never!

Comment: I believe that most GPS-based cycling computers use GPS to determine altitude.  Generally that's going to be much more accurate than an uncalibrated pressure-based altimeter.

Comment: @jwh20 GPS is not very good for altitude. It will be better than an altimeter with the wrong altimeter setting, but the vertical ascent/descent should certainly be more accurate from pressure-based sensors. The drift during the day can be accounted for from the start/end difference or simply from the weather forecast or measurement graphs. They are very accurate for pressure or geopotential height.

Comment: @jwh20 : Look at the casing of the GPS. If there is a small hole (<1mm) the altimeter is barometric. The Garmins all have it.

Comment: @Carel Garmins of a certain age, I assume. My old etrex certainly does not have it. Alse, holes can have differnt purpose (I assume it is a speaker on my cheap Teasi).

Comment: @VladimirF It's at sea level. The standard reference pressure is 101.3 kPa not 113 kPa.

Comment: @juhist Ups, sorry. Too much used to hPa and forget the zero.

Comment: In reality, the devices with both GPS and pressure sensor use the pressure sensor for precise measurements and GPS for calibrating the base level. Pressure-based sensors are also quite sensitive to turbulence, and that's another reason why you can't really track every small change for climb totals.

Comment: @ojs Can you explain how are those sensors sensitive to turbulence? If placed incorrectly, they could act like a pitot tube, but then they would mainly be sensitive to the relative wind speed and only as a perturbation of that to turbulence. In any case, turbulence normally should no cause variations of more than a few Pascal (probably less than one) and that variation should look like noise.

Comment: @VladimirF how would you place a sensor correctly? Any source for the numbers?

Comment: @ojs Any source for the fact that it is sensitive at all? The numbers are a rough estimate from Bernoulli.

Comment: @VladimirF no public source, sorry. I know because I implemented the altitude calculation to a certain consumer product and have seen the raw data. You can buy a pressure sensor and see how the numbers look like when you blow into it, though.

Comment: My bicycle computer altimeter has such a long measurement interval, that if blowing to the sensor momentarily, it would be unaffected by the blowing. The blowing would need to be continuous. Turbulence by definition is not continuous.

Comment: I have no idea if the sensor in your computer does continuous measurement, but my bet would be heavy filtering after measurement. The sensor I had took a sub-millisecond sample. Now, because of the random nature of the turbulence, any of these samples could be off in either direction.

Comment: @ojs I do know how pressure works, fluid dynamics is my job. What kind of "sensitive" are you speaking of? You can't make bigger fluctuation than what comes from the Bernoulli equation. However, even that the maximum assumes it acts as a Pitot tube and that is not generally true, the manufacturers are not crazy. If you place it correctly, it rather acts like an aircraft static port. Anyway, the changes in bicycle speed and orientation relative to the mean wind is **much** more important than turbulence. Perhaps your "consumer product" was fixed or not moving in the wind field?

Comment: And, as juhist mentions, what turbulence really does with pressure-field is noise, it can be dealt with, the mean wind is much worse. Be aware that even pitot tubes that use pressure differences to measure velocity often just measure the mean wind and are not very sensitive to turbulence, or to any other high-frequency noise.

Comment: @VladimirF near sea level, random errors up to 80 Pa. These numbers were from high speed descents, so it's difficult to tell the effect of constant wind field at the same time. Yes, I know that noise can be filtered and nobody did a good job at it at the time. I don't really want to go into more details.

Comment: @ojs 80 Pa corresponds to 11 m/s (in a pitot tube), that is quite a lot for turbulence at the bicycle height and would correspond to very strong mean winds. But even in these extreme situations just traveling at 30 km/h in or out of the wind makes a bigger change.

Comment: @VladimirF 11 m/s on the other hand corresponds to less than half of the speeds some people pull off in mountain descents.

Comment: @ojs That's exactly what I am saying! That is not turbulence, however, that is mean wind. There are even pitot tube systems for certain head units. For that to work, the other pressure sensor must act like a static port and hence be very in-sensitive to the wind.

Comment: @VladimirF Well, the sensor isn't pointing to wind for obvious reasons. The airflow around a bike computer, watch or other isn't smooth. So, at any moment there is going to be airflow at unpredictable speed to unpredictable direction. What could be the word for this phenomenon?

Comment: It is the relative wind https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relative_wind The placement of the static port is easier on a plane, because the main component is always in the direction of travel, unless being very very slow. Still the concept of being able to place one sensor that detects the "dynamic pressure" and other sensor for the pressure not-affected by the flow around the object (static pressure) is crucial for this speed detection method.

Comment: Okay. I thought we were arguing about altitude measurement and difficulties in measuring the static pressure.

Comment: >> Also, good cycle computers allow you to set several home locations and their altitudes.  == the home location altitude/pressure is irrelevent for barometric computers calculating altitude climbed.

Comment: @juhist The the indicated altitude difference after your trip has not too much to do with the altitude error of the altitude difference climbed or descended. It is only the low limit, you know the error is bigger than that. It is basically caused by the difference in the sea level pressure between the start time and the end time. But the integration of all those movement in between can still be incorrect in various other ways.